# Merge (concat) all video file present in '43. DP (Part1)' and put it into '43. DP (Part1)' and give name merged (concat) file to folder name

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python, video-conversion

I have parent folder `alpha part 3` which contain child folder `43. DP (Part1)`, `44. DP (Part2)`, `45. DP (Part3)`.

I want to merge (concat) all video file present in `43. DP (Part1)` and put it into `43. DP (Part1)` and give name merged (concat) file to folder name.

And as it is do for all.

```
alpha part 3
├── 43. DP (Part1)
│   ├── _43.1_Introduction to DP.mp4
│   ├── _43.2_What is DP_ (Definition).mp4
│   ├── _43.3_Ways of DP.mp4
│   ├── _43.4_7 Important Concepts.mp4
│   ├── _43.5_Climbing Stairs (Recursion).mp4
│   ├── _43.6_Climbing Stairs (Memoization DP).mp4
│   ├── _43.7_Climbing Stairs Variation.mp4
│   └── _43.8_Climbing Stairs (Tabulation DP).mp4
├── 44. DP (Part2)
│   ├── _44.1_Types of Knapsack problems.mp4
│   ├── _44.2_0-1 Knapsack (Recursion).mp4
│   ├── _44.3_0-1 Knapsack (Memoization).mp4
│   ├── _44.4_0-1 Knapsack (Tabulation).mp4
│   ├── _44.5_Target Sum Subset (Tabulation).mp4
│   ├── _44.6_Target Sum Subset (Code).mp4
│   └── _44.7_Unbounded Knapsack (Tabulation).mp4
├── 45. DP (Part3)
│   ├── _45.1_Coin Change (Live Class).mp4
│   ├── _45.2_Rod Cutting.mp4
│   ├── _45.3_Longest Common Subsequence (Recursion).mp4
│   ├── _45.4_LCS (Memoization).mp4
│   └── _45.5_LCS (Tabulation).mp4
```

Right or is any way to go this at once. Write Python code with FFmpeg.

My Python code is as follows; what do I need to adjust?

```python
import os
import subprocess

# Function to merge videos in a folder
def merge_videos_in_folder(folder_path):
    print(f"Merging videos in folder: {folder_path}")

    # Use FFmpeg to concatenate all video files within the folder
    cmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-f", "concat",
        "-safe", "0",
        "-i", "<(find '{}' -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec echo 'file {{}}' \;)".format(folder_path),
        "-c", "copy",
        os.path.join(folder_path, "merged_video.mp4")
    ]
    subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)

    print(f"Videos merged for folder: {folder_path}")

# Specify the directory containing folders with video files
parent_dir = "/path/to/parent_directory"

# Loop through each folder in the input directory
for folder in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(parent_dir, folder)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        # Merge videos in the current folder
        merge_videos_in_folder(folder_path)

print("All videos merged successfully!")
```

Comment: This site does not *write* scripts, but if you can show your work, you could get help on your script.